Picklist values by Record type in LWC
I have approximately 30 record types on Opportunity object. I want to fetch the Opportunity type values for each record type and display in a datatable. I tried to get with the below code but the reactive parameter $recordTypeId only works for the last record type id.
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT })
            getobjectInfo(result) {
                if (result.data) {
                
                let recordtypeinfo = [];
                recordtypeinfo = result.data.recordTypeInfos;
                console.log('recordtypeinfo==>'+JSON.stringify(recordtypeinfo));
                    for (let i in recordtypeinfo){
                        if(recordtypeinfo[i].available){
                            this.recordTypeId = recordtypeinfo[i].recordTypeId;
                        }
                        console.log('i==>'+JSON.stringify(recordtypeinfo[i]));
                    }
                }
        }

   @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId:'$recordTypeId', fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD })
   loaddata({error, data}){
    console.log('getPicklistValues '+data.values);
        if(error){
            console.log('error 1111', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error)));
        }else if(data){
            console.log('data 1111', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
            const picklistValues = data;
        } 
    } 

